# How to make request http repeatedly?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a http request that depends on parameters `this.parameters`:

```
public getData() {
  this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.URL_PATH}/getData`, {
       params: HttpParamsBuilder.buildQueryParams(this.parameters),
  });
}
```

I use it in template:

```
{{ getData | async }}
```

Parameters could be changed in runtime somewhere in app.

How to call this method repeatedly when `this.parameters` are changed?

I don't want to pollute component like this:

```
this.parameters.changes().subscribe((data) => {
     this.serviceHttp.getData();
});
```

How do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rxjs operator switchMap (or concatMap, mergeMap, exhaustMap etc. It depends on your desire response handling. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators)

```
class SomeComponent {
  data$ = this.parameters.changes().pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.serviceHttp.getData())
  );
}
```

and use it in your template as `data$ | async`